# Permanently reverse the order of a DataTable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Let's say I have a Data Table like so:

```
<table id="history" class="display">
    <thead>
       
        <th>Player</th>
        <th>Word</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Message</th>

    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a function that receives a payload from the server and adds a row to the datatable with the relevant information

```
     var history_data_table = $('#history').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 5,
            "searching": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "Words that you discover will appear here."
            }
        });


 function liveRecv(word_payload) {
            history_data_table.row.add([word_payload.id_in_group,
                word_payload.word,
                word_payload.word_value,
                word_payload.message]
            ).draw();
```

Naturally, this will add the row to the end of a paginated table.  This table is a list of transactions in a game, and I want to present the most recent transactions to the user, such that every row that's added is added to the top of the data-table.  What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this method using `jQuery`

```
$('#history tr:first').after("<tr role="row"><td></td><td>add you own row</td></tr>");
```

or you could use `DataTables` inner function to access the `array` of `rows`

```
var history_data_table = $('#history').dataTable();
var DisplayMaster = history_data_table.fnSettings()['aiDisplayMaster'];
var tableapi = history_data_table.api();
var getlastrow = DisplayMaster.pop();
DisplayMaster.unshift(getlastrow);
tableapi.draw(false);
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems like the first option will break pagination? And I'm not sure I understand what's going on with the second result.  Should I first add the news rows before running the second set of lines?

Comment: yes you should add the news rows first and then use  the rest of the code

Comment: `var tableapi = history_data_table.api();` takes the last row which is the raw you added and then move it to the top of the array using `unshift()`

Comment: What does the `table` in `table.fnSettings()` refer to?  Should it be `history_data_table`?

Comment: it's typo change it to `history_data_table`

Comment: I'm getting the error: `history_data_table.fnSettings is not a function`  Not sure what the issue is.  The first option has promise... I only really need to track the most recent submission.  So I can just add that bit of javascript to the top... but I'd need to pop it off before adding the next one, so the table doesn't grow without bound.  Do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: can you add your code or make jsfiddle, and I will check it out